# Reuse asmack connection or recreate it in case of disconnect ( including broken TCP connections) in a safe way?

Tags: android, asmack

I'm coding a chat app, and I'm using asmack client library ( thank you Flow for maintain it :) ). The problem is I don't know how to handle disconnects ( normals, that are notified by connection listeners or broken TCP's caused ones )

Let's say I create the connection on thread A, that is I call connect & login on the same thread.

If, for any reason I will be disconnected, then next time, should I:

- reuse the same XMPPConnection reference declared as volatile, and call connect on it on another thread? ( since Android doesn't let me call IO on main thread?). I don't really like this idea because most of the variables from XMPPConnection are not volatile, so calling connect on the same XMPPConnection from multiple threads ( one at a time, so after each disconnect I recall connect on a new thread ) could be problematic regarding thread safety.
- recreate the XMPPConnection and clean-up the old one? Here is also a catch because while transition to the second connection, you could lose some messages. I am thinking of using a queue to hold my messages and write them as soon as a connection is available.

I know XMPP provides ping to detect if the server is still around, but if you do a ping at 1 min, but the connection becomes broken ( you remove the LAN cable from the wireless router to which you're connected with the phone, then Android will not notify you of connection lost, and you can still send messages on the socket for a time ), how can you achieve message sent integrity?

I am thinking to send some messages (ping ) synchronous, something like getRoster is implemented in XMPPConnection. That way if I don't receive a message after a timeout ( default in smack is 5 seconds ), then I will disconnect from XMPP, assuming my connection is broken. Do you think it's a good idea to rely on timeout or I can get screwed on mobile data connection?

The app that I want to make has WhatsApp's style, so it should work offline and resend messages when it relogins. If you have some recommendations about it, please share.

Many thanks,

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I m facing the same one

Comment: Hi, since I want to create a very stable chat app, I intend to write my own library. Smack was just not meant to be thread safe. Think you have a XMPPConnection. You call connect on thread 1, then disconnect for some reason ( internet down, etc ). If you have that put into a running service then when you call again connect this time on another thread t2, it's doesn't look safe. If you want to create/recreate the connection, you must have some kind of queue to put packets that you may send during the transition between those 2. If you have questions about SMACK please ask me :)

Comment: Let move with your point 1 i.e should we reuse the existing xmppConnection (mXmppCon.connect()) or should we clean up the connection and recreate the xmppConnection again. What should be a good way?

Comment: I think recreating. See https://code.google.com/p/gtalksms/source/checkout for what they did

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay connected all the time after established connection first time then i think you could try to maintain your connection in `Service` class of android.

> The app that I want to make has WhatsApp's style, so it should work
>   offline and resend messages when it relogins

You need to make one Broadcast receiver which monitor when your data connection goes off and on .According that event you need to re-establish xmpp connection again (in other words start that service again )

Morevere , that was some brief but its yet lot more to manage in your case .I suggest one of my favorite  opensource application  [GTalkSMS](https://code.google.com/p/gtalksms/) which may help you to understand how to deal with xmpp connection .